# MySQL Link to PHPMyAdmin/MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql database stored on a server via phpmyadmin. I want to link this to MS Access for other users. I often link mysql databases to MS Access which are stored locally, but never DB's stored on a server.

Is it possible to do a ODBC connection to a remote database through MS Access?

Comment: "I have a mysql database stored on a server via phpmyadmin". No, you have a MySQL database stored on a server that you administer using phpmyadmin. It's very easy to do a remote ODBC connection, but that kind of question doesn't belong on this site. I will flag it for migration